# My 5 minute interval query is working on 5.5.6 version but not working in 5.5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 minute interval query and it's working on 
(i) Localhost and
(ii) Server version: 5.5.61-38.13-log - Percona Server (GPL)
But Not working on
 **Server version: 5.7.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)**

```
Select MIN(language_code) as language_code 
FROM master_analytics 
WHERE is_active = 1 
      AND entry_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE 
GROUP BY language_code
```

Actually, I want acheive only language name if i run query for 5 minute and result is show how many languages name are inserted in 5 miutes. I know it's version problem but how to solve it.

Comment: anybuddy have  solutions ?

Comment: Your query makes no sense whatsoever; you are grouping on the field and then aggregating (min()) on the same field. What exactly is this query trying to achieve ? Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Actually, I want acheive only language name if i run query for 5 minute and result is show how many languages name are inserted in 5 miutes.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` is unnecessary here, based on your [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685997/my-5-minute-interval-query-is-working-on-5-5-6-version-but-not-working-in-5-5-7?noredirect=1#comment101819011_57685997). Moreover, you are grouping on a field and then aggregating (`min()`) on the same field, which does not make any sense, and hence giving wrong results.

You simply need `DISTINCT` (get unique `language_code` values inserted in last 5 minutes):

```
Select DISTINCT language_code 
FROM master_analytics 
WHERE is_active = 1 
      AND entry_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Comment: Thanks for reply me. these one  is also tryed and i have unique id  and also i used id   for 5 minute interval

Comment: For example in last five minute i  inserted only english language,  and 30 minutes above i'm inserted french language. but when i run the query in phpmyadmin it's show both language.

Comment: You need to give sample data so that we can test further. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Actualy i told in my question. it's not working only 5.7.27 version

Comment: @PradeepDhakad the query you have specified, and other variations (as given in my answer) are too basic to be behaving differently in 5.5 and 5.7 versions of MySQL. There is something else happening; and it can only be solved if we know the exact table structure that you are using with exact datatypes being used; some sample data would also help.